# jQuery Validation engine Dynamic field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using jQuery validation engine for field validation

On page load there are already fields available, and the validation works correct
for them, but there are some buttons which add fields dynamically, and those
validations won't work obviously :) I tried initializing the instance again but it 
doesn't work.

Is there a method by which I can manually add validation instance to those field which 
I have added dynamically

EDIT: Sorry forgot to mention, I'm using this plugin
http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/index.html

Thanks,
Mo

Comment: post some codes what you've tried

Comment: jQuery Validation plugin will validate all fields in HTML that is marked to require validation.

Answer (score 1):

This article helped me very much: http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/

You should validate a container in which you have dynamically added elements

Comment: I am sorry but the plugin I am using is http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/index.html, not the basistance one which is mentioned in the link above. :(